Changing a color in an image via the command line / colorizing the image
I have a set of images that need a color dynamically applied to them to "colorize" them. The image itself is the "white" representation and certain colors need to be applied dynamically.
GIMP does a wonderful job of that by going to "Colors" -> "Colorize" and then I can enter the target RGB color and it will be applied. However I need something like this in CLI mode (for Windows).
I have tried "BIMP" and its colorify plugin and it does the same thing - but again not in CLI mode.
I also checked if Inkscape can accomplish this (as I am using this successfully for other use cases) but I did not find a solution.
I also tried ImageMagick, but my search did not turn up anything of use.
Also I checked the WA2L tools (which helped a lot in a different use case -> svg2png) but again: nothing
Do any of you have a pointer (or maybe even a full solution) to colorize the image as required.
The idea is that I have a picture of a white part and we offer that part in any color but we do not want to save thousands of copies of the same image just to have it in different colors.
Example input:

Example output after colorizing it via BIMP with RGB color 161/143/131 (a brown shade):


Example input and output please!

OP edited with examples

In Imagemagick 7, you can try, (change tan to your exact color)
magick image.png -channel rgb -fill tan -colorize 100 result1.png


or probably better
magick image.png \( -clone 0 -channel rgb -fill tan -colorize 100 \) +swap -compose multiply -composite result2.png



Thank you for the solution. Unfortunately it throws an error when I try it under Windows: magick: unable to open image '(': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3596. Do I need to escape the (  and if so, how?

Nevermind, I found the error. If I remove the backslashes it seems to work. I will test it some more but so far it looks good. Thank you!

Correct: under Windows there is no need for escapes to the parentheses. In the future, best to identify your OS and your version of Imagemagick when asking a question, as syntax may vary.
